# SQL: concatenate every group of N rows into a single row

Tags: mysql, sql, string, count, pivot

I have this

```
ID | Name | Age | Number | Date of Registration 
------------------------------------------------
1  | Peter| 23  | 472845 | 20190826
2  | Mary | 16  | 543342 | 20200310
3  | Li   | 53  | 328712 | 20171124
4  | Eric |  8  | 798072 | 20181222
5  | Dan  | 27  | 909123 | 20200101
```

I want to concatenate groups of N rows into a single row. For N = 2, this would give me this

```
1, Peter, 23, 472845, 20190826 | 2, Mary, 16, 543342, 20200310
3, Li, 53, 328712, 20171124 |4, Eric, 8, 798072, 20181222
5, Dan, 27, 909123, 20200101
```

If possible, I'd like to keep the record splitter | between 2 lines for later usage but okay to replace with comma. Later usage is not related to the query itself so not discussed here, but can be use cases like updating member information, where | is used as record splitter and if | is not available I can also define a record using regex.

I tried stuff() but what if N = 100? Does anyone have better ideas? Maybe group_concat?

Thanks!

Comment: What is 'later usage'?

Comment: Later usage is not related to the query itself so not discussed here, but can be use cases like updating member information, where | is used as record splitter and if | is not available I can also define a record using regex.

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation:

```
select group_concat(
    concat_ws(', ', id, name, age, number, date_of_registration) 
    order by id
    separator ' | ' 
) val
from mytable
group by floor((id - 1) / 2)
```

You control the number of rows per group with the denominator of the division in the `group by` clause (currently `2`).

This assumes that `id` starts at `1` and increment without gaps. Else, we can generate our own sequence with `row_number()`:

```
select group_concat(
    concat_ws(', ', id, name, age, number, date_of_registration) 
    order by id
    separator ' | ' 
) val
from (select t.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn mytable) t
group by floor((rn - 1) / 2)
```

`concat_ws()` forces the conversion to strings, and skips `null` values. If you want to represent these `null` values in the resultset, then you need `colaesce()` around each nullable column, like:

```
concat_ws(',', id, coalesce(name, ''), age, number, date_of_registration)
```

Comment: if I understand correctly, either approach requires to have a numeric column like id right? if we only have string columns like name, address, comment, etc then the grouping won't work

Comment: @user5458359: the `id` column is used to *order* the records (not to sort them). Technically, using the second query, you can use any column (or set of columns) that you like, including strings. One thing to keep in mind: if you want stable, predicable results, then that (set of) column(s) should not contain duplicates.